# According to memory allocation in program what is different between enum ,struct,union , classes, Interface and its relation between them

Tags: class, struct, enums, interface, union

I am little bit confuse about the memory allocation for **enum** , **struct**, **union** , **classes**, **Interface** and also clear my concept which one is better between enum, union and struct in which point means when i use these

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: All these are programming constructs used for different purpose. Any good read will tell you the difference by looking at examples.

Comment: @StephenC i am talking about Android/Java language.

Comment: Well for a start, there is no `struct` data type in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer pertains to Java:

To the extent that your question makes sense, there is no difference in memory allocation for those constructs in Java.

- Enum instances are allocated in the heap.  (An `enum` is a reference type in Java.)
- Instances of classes are allocated in the heap.
- Instances of interfaces don't exist per strictly speaking.  An instance of an interface is actually an instance of a class that implements the interface.  (It might be an anonymous class ... but it is a class nonetheless.)
- Java does not have `union` or `struct` data types.

---

<sup>The above contains a small "white lie".  In fact, some recent JVM JIT compilers are capable of deducing that the object being created has a lifetime that corresponds to the current method call.  They can then allocate the object in the stack frame rather than on the heap.  However, this happens transparently to the program / programmer.</sup>